# Missing SharePoint List Column in List View Group by section

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, grouping

I have a list with single line text, Choice and dropdown list columns. I would like to group the dropdown list column

But I see the dropdown column missing in the group by section of list view.

Can any one help me what might be the issue?

Comment: What is the type of that column?

Comment: Choice Column ,And Display choice selection is Drop-down

Comment: Single or multiple choice?

Answer (score 3):

By Default, items in a SharePoint list can't be grouped by a Choice field if it allows multiple selections (checkbox).

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2009/09/solved-cant-group-by-choice-column-in.html