# Create a SharePoint view base on Choice column (Checkboxes allow multiple selections)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, grouping

I have a SharePoint online document library with a Choice column. I have selected Checkboxes so users can have multiple selections options. My issue is that when I want to use Group by an option to create a new view, I can't see this column in the list of selections.

Would you mind letting me know first if there is another way to achieve my goal and second if I am doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in SharePoint. Choice column with multiple selections does not support grouping in views.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Missing SharePoint List Column in List View Group by section](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177718/missing-sharepoint-list-column-in-list-view-group-by-section)
2. [SharePoint view group by multi value field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168694/sharepoint-view-group-by-multi-value-field)
3. [Group By on Choice column on which allow multiple selection is checked](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/49710e43-0725-4219-9a45-f6eccae4c021/group-by-on-choice-column-on-which-allow-multiple-selection-is-checked?forum=SP2016)
4. [Code to create view and group it by choice column which allows multiple selection](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0af5d1a5-e047-483f-ae55-0b5695604944/code-to-create-view-and-group-it-by-choice-column-which-allows-multiple-selection?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this help? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is by default that we cannot group by items based on a choice column.

You can submit a feedback here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. It is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products. What's more, if a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it will be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.